# Different states of one image

Tags: android, image, android-layout, layout

I am making an app for Andorid. There are 2 restrictions:

- It must be light (2-3MB)
- I need to have minimal graphic files (not having a file in diffrent state and option)

How to make the layout so I can modify only the red dots (image or code) for each option that is selected?

Making 6 different states of this image is not a good answer (too big data)

[image: Power button On with sleceted field]

Comment: Does the button need to be that big?

Comment: elaborate your question

Comment: you can have the big grey thing be the background (or the base layer of a layer-list), and the dots be images in a relative layout or an inset drawable.

Comment: @shapeshifter Yes it's the main Button for the App :(  ok but it will work for all smarthphones (i little woried about the scale problem)

Answer (score 0):

Make this image as two layered. One for your main button, and other for red dots(They should be PNG's and 6 of them for different dots).And place these PNG above your main button according to the choice(Make them visible/invisible). Do you have its PSD file btw?

Comment: Will it be scale-able  ? I litte woried about non-stadard graphics that are no (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi). Word of Advice ?

Comment: you should set width and height of all images as wrap_content.Then only they will arrange correctly.And will consume less size, bcos those images with red dot will have only couple of bites.Try to place images inside a relative layout, and arrange all as center to that layout